# How can disable auto generation invoice in Magento 1.9.3.1?

Tags: paypal, magento1.9.3.1

I need to disable the auto invoice created by magento after a paypal payment.

The magento version is 1.9.3.1 and no settings are present to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the below file:

> app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php

To:

> app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php

You can see how magento create invoice for paypal orders like below:

Find the below code in **Ipn.php**  which creates invoice for paypal orders.

```
if ($invoice = $payment->getCreatedInvoice()) { $message = Mage::helper('paypal')->__('Notified customer about invoice #%s.', $invoice->getIncrementId()); $comment = $order->sendNewOrderEmail()->addStatusHistoryComment($message) ->setIsCustomerNotified(true) ->save(); }
```

And change the code like below:

```
$order->sendNewOrderEmail() ->setIsCustomerNotified(true) ->save();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Use rewrite method it will be save!!

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't works..

Comment: Can you trying change the same thing in your core file? Also this is for standard paypal. Are you doing it for express?

Comment: Yes I tried, but nothing. I'm using standard and express.

Comment: For standard it should work. Need to debug then.